# Low Power Consumption with Ultrasonic Sensor (US-100, HC-SR04)

Tags: pcb-design, low-power

I have designed a Zigbee sensor to measure the water level in the cistern. It should be operated with batteries, so the ultrasonic sensor should only be activated for measurement. With the current scheme I have a consumption of 0.08 mA in sleep mode. If I only look at CC2530, it consumes 1µA in sleep mode.

The measurement is done like this: The sensor goes out of sleep mode, pin 1.0 is set high, measurement is taken and pin 1.0 is set low and then back into sleep mode.
When I measure the voltage on the sensor (US-100) in sleep mode, I have about 0.4V. Unfortunately, I can't get any further with the troubleshooting :(

[image]

Comment: Add some resistors in series with trig/echo lines. The IO pins are providing a "weak" supply for the device.

Comment: Is the better way near to sensor or to cc2530 pins?
Which resistor value should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. US-100 works just fine from 3V, so there's no need for the boost converter. Just use US-100, not HC-04.
2. There's no need for the GND-disconnecting mosfet even when using U5 switcher.
3. P0.2 and P0.3 needs to be driven to logical zero when the sensor is turned off. Yes, P0.2 should be turned into an *output* and driven low when the sensor is not in use.

If you are OK using only US-100, then the following will do the trick:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzUGDu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Sensor pseudo-code:

```
set_dir(P0_2, INPUT);
set(P1_0, LO); // enable the sensor
sleep(100*US); // wait for sensor to initialize
measure_distance();
set(P1_0, HI); // disable the sensor
set_dir(P0_2, OUTPUT);
set(P0_2, LO);
set(P0_3, LO);
```

If you insist on using HC-04 powered from 5V, then you'll want the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2focS99.png)</sup>

Sensor pseudo-code:

```
set_dir(P0_2, INPUT);
set(P1_1, LO); // turn on the sensor VCC switch
set(P1_0, HI); // turn on the 5V switcher
sleep(1*ms); // wait for sensor to initialize
measure_distance();
set(P1_0, LO); // turn off the 5V switcher
set(P1_1, HI); // turn off the sensor VCC switch
// U2 will now discharge C5 and Q2 will fully turn off
set_dir(P0_2, OUTPUT);
set(P0_2, LO);
set(P0_3, LO);
```

Comment: My thoughts were, if I use 2xAAA batteries, they provide 3V at the beginning, with time the voltage goes down. CC2530 can still work up to 2V, but US-100 cannot. That's why I wanted to solve it with the DC-DC booster.

Is it not the case that when CC2530 goes into sleep mode, all pins go LOW? That means that P1.1 also goes LOW?

As I can see from your diagram, MT3608 is not completely switched off, but consumes approx. 1µA according to the data sheet?

Comment: I use US-100 in UART mode, In this case, should I also drive p0.2 and p0.3 low?

Comment: 1uA will also be a mosfet leakage when it gets hot, so you can’t completely avoid all leakage with mosfet control. You can certainly move the high-side mosfet in front of the switcher. I’ll update the answer to that effect. And yes, you must drive all control signals low no matter what mode they are. That’s where your current drains are. Put a series resistor in line with those circuits and measure for yourself. For minimum off leakage you’d need a BJT pass transistor, at expense of wasting base current when on. You could generate 5V completely under MCU control as well, using a discrete sw.

Comment: Which transistor would you recommend? Unfortunately, I am not a professional in schematic technology. I didn't quite understand your last sentence, how else can I generate 5V?

Answer (score 2):

Could it be this current path?
[image]

Comment: Hmm, I would say, it is possible. Should I change GND to D. If Q2 is off, this way will be blocked?

Comment: @Diddlik *it is possible* - it's not "possible", that's where your current goes, among other places.

Comment: You also have 3 volts minus D1 forward voltage drop supplying the ultrasonic module. Could that be another source of current consumption?

Comment: @Diddlik You may be able to disconnect the ground for the entire boost converter circuit, yes, however, be careful with the enable signal (and the sensor Tx/Rx) because chips generally don't like their inputs being lower than ground. You might want to connect the enable signal permanently on in this case.